# Kate editor: how to define / add filetype filters in file dialogs?

Tags: kde, editors, kate

I use Kate extensively. When opening and saving files, I would like to have several pre-defined options to filter by filetype (extension). In Arch Linux Kate only shows the "All Files" filter in file dialogs. In Ubuntu 16.04 Kate does not show any filters at all in the file dialogs.

I would like to know how to:

1. define a Kate filetype filter such as "plain text" with extension ".txt".
2. make my chosen filter the default in Kate file dialogs (open, save, save-as).

Background:

Trying the steps [here](https://kate-editor.org/2006/02/09/kate-modes-filetypes/) did not accomplish my goal. This appears to be for a different purpose maybe? As far as I can tell, these steps only take effect after the document is open. My goal is to filter the files shown in the dialog (before opening one).